# Appending 2x2 co variance matrices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array such as:

gmm.sigma =

```
[[[ 4.64 -1.93]
  [-1.93  6.5 ]]
 [[ 3.65  2.89]
  [ 2.89 -1.26]]]
```

and I want to add another 2x2 matrix such as:

gauss.sigma=

```
[[ -1.24  2.34]
 [  2.34  4.76]]
```

to get:

gmm.sigma =

```
[[[ 4.64 -1.93]
  [-1.93  6.5 ]]
 [[ 3.65  2.89]
  [ 2.89 -1.26]]
 [[-1.24  2.34]
  [ 2.34  4.76]]]
```

I have tried: `gmm.sigma = np.append(gmm.sigma, gauss.sigma, axis = 0)`,
but get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 40, in <module>
    gmm.sigma = np.append(gmm.sigma, gauss.sigma, axis = 0)
  File "/home/rowan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4528, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Note that the error shows a call to concatenate. It's a good idea to learn how to use that function directly.  You want to join a (2,2,2) with a (2,2).  Somehow that 2nd one needs an added dimension, possibly (1,2,2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to join the 2 arrays on the first axis - except that the second is only 2d.  It needs an added dimension:

```
In [233]: arr = np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2)
In [234]: arr1 = np.arange(10,14).reshape(2,2)
In [235]: np.concatenate((arr, arr1[None,:,:]), axis=0)
Out[235]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[10, 11],
        [12, 13]]])
```

`dstack` is a variation on `concatenate` that expands everything to 3d, and joins on the last axis.  To use it we have to transpose everything:

```
In [236]: np.dstack((arr.T,arr1.T)).T
Out[236]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[10, 11],
        [12, 13]]])
```

`index_tricks` adds some classes that play similar tricks with dimensions:

```
In [241]: np.r_['0,3', arr, arr1]
Out[241]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[10, 11],
        [12, 13]]])
```

The docs of `np.r_` require some reading if you want get most from it, but it might worth using if you had to adjust the dimensions of several arrays, eg.  `np.r_['0,3',  arr1, arr, arr1]`

Comment: For those interested as per @hpaulj 's suggestion. see  the documentation and code for … class RClass(AxisConcatenator) … https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e26c2990c4828d6f7f2f588d75cd01eecafd53f3/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) which stacks the arrays in sequence depth wise (along the third axis) followed by a transpose. To get the desired output, you will have to stack `gmm.T` and `gauss`

```
gmm = np.array([[[4.64, -1.93],
                [-1.93, 6.5 ]],
                [[3.65, 2.89],
                 [2.89, -1.26]]])

gauss = np.array([[ -1.24, 2.34],
                  [2.34, 4.76]])


result = np.dstack((gmm.T, gauss)).T
print (result)
print (result.shape)
# (3, 2, 2)
```

---

**Output**

```
array([[[ 4.64, -1.93],
    [-1.93,  6.5 ]],

   [[ 3.65,  2.89],
    [ 2.89, -1.26]],

   [[-1.24,  2.34],
    [ 2.34,  4.76]]])
```

**Alternatively** you can also use concatenate by properly reshaping your second array as

```
gmm = np.array([[[4.64, -1.93],
                [-1.93, 6.5 ]],
                [[3.65, 2.89],
                 [2.89, -1.26]]])

gauss = np.array([[ -1.24, 2.34],
                  [2.34, 4.76]]).reshape(1,2,2)

result = np.concatenate((gmm, gauss), axis=0)
```

Comment: Values `result[0, 0, 1], result[0, 1, 1], result[1, 0, 0], result[1, 1, 0]` don't coincide with the expected output, does it matter?

Comment: @SebastianPalma: Oh sorry. Check my edited answer. I forgot a transpose. Thanks for reminding

Comment: Maybe you don't need all those transpose.

Comment: @hpaulj : I already called it a day and would appreciate if you could just edit it :)  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As the error message stated, the dimension of `gmm` and `gauss_sigma`are not the same, you should reshape `gauss_sigma` before appending.

```
gmm_sigma = np.array([[[4.64, -1.93], [-1.93, 6.5]], [[3.65, 2.89], [ 2.89, -1.26]]])
gauss_sigma = np.array([[-1.24, 2.34], [2.34, 4.76]])

print(np.append(gmm_sigma, gauss_sigma.reshape(1, 2, 2), axis=0))
# array([[[ 4.64, -1.93],
#         [-1.93,  6.5 ]],
# 
#        [[ 3.65,  2.89],
#         [ 2.89, -1.26]],
# 
#        [[-1.24,  2.34],
#         [ 2.34,  4.76]]])
```